# Can not load css sometimes

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

Again i am stucked and need your help. I can not load css on my web-page sometimes. Actually, Yesterday it was working fine but today it was not loading. So, I have deleted that whole folder and uploaded another one which one I was using on localhost. Then again it was working fine for sometime. After restarting the browser I'm facing the problem.

Here are the details about my code:

Controller: `Users.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
class Users extends CI_Controller
{

    public function viewinsert1()
    {

        $this->load->view('createfinal');
    }

    public function viewinsert2()
    {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
        $this->load->view('personalfinal');
    }

    public function viewinsert3()
    {

        $this->load->view('socialfinal');
    }

    public function viewupdate()
    {

        $this->load->view('view_update');
    }

    public function viewdelete()
    {

        $this->load->view('view_delete');
    }

    public function show()
    {
        // $this->load->model('user_model');
        $data['results'] = $this->user_model->get_users();


        $this->load->view('user_view', $data);

        // foreach ($result as $object) 
        // {
        //  echo $object->id . "</br>"; 
        // }
    }

    // public function insert()
    // {

    //  $username = "Peter";
    //  $password = "12345";
    //  $this->user_model->create_users([
    //      'username' => $username,
    //      'password' => $password
    //      ]);
    // }

    public function insert()
    {
        // echo $this->input->post('password') . "</br>";
        // echo $_POST['username'];


        //echo $email = $this->input->post('email');
        //echo $_SESSION["email"];
        // $email  = $this->input->post('email');


        // $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
        // $_SESSION["pass"] = $pass;
        // $_SESSION["cpass"] = $cpass;
        // $_SESSION["fname"] = $fname;
        // $_SESSION["lname"] = $lname;
        // $_SESSION["phone"] = $phone;
        // $_SESSION["address"] = $address;
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'firstname', 'trim|alpha|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'lastname', 'trim|alpha|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'phone', 'trim|numeric|required|integer|exact_length[10]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'address', 'trim|alpha_dash|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'cpass', 'trim|required|matches[cpass]|md5');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'cpass', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('createfinal');
            echo "Error";
        }

        else
        {
            $data = array(
                    'email' => $_SESSION["email"],
                    'firstname' => $_SESSION["fname"],
                    'lastname' => $_SESSION["lname"],
                    'phone' => $_SESSION["phone"],
                    'address' => $_SESSION["address"],
                    'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
                    'facebook' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
                    'googleplus' => $this->input->post('gplus'),
                    'password' => $_SESSION["pass"],
                    'confirm' => $_SESSION["cpass"], 
                    );

        // echo var_dump($data);


        $result = $this->user_model->create_users($data);

        $this->load->view('createfinal');

        echo "<h1>The data has been inserted</h1>";
        }
    }

    public function update()
    {

        if (isset($_POST['update'])) 
        {

            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'password' => $this->input->post('password')
                          );

            $this->user_model->update_users($data, $id);

            echo "<h1> Data is updated successfully:) </h1>";
            $this->load->view('view_update');
        }
        else
        {

            echo "Oops! There is something wrong!";
        }

    }

    public function delete()
    {

        if (isset($_POST['delete'])) 
        {

            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $this->user_model->delete_users($id);

            echo "<h1>The data has been deleted.</h1>";

        }
        else
        {

            echo "<h3>No Such data exist!</h3>";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

and here is the view that i wanna load..

`createfinal.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform" action="viewinsert2" method="post">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li>Social Profiles</li>
        <li>Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
        <input type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>


</body>
</html>
```

The css folder is parallel to the application folder.

Comment: Try this    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/css/style.css">

Comment: can you show the content of `application\config\config.php` ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/css/style.css">

Comment: you just forget "/" before css

Comment: I see your `base_url` is set to a localhost address. Is the problem happening locally or on the server?

Comment: Yup, I have tried all the solutions. But it is still not working. and it was working correctly ago 5-7 hours.

Comment: what do you get when you `print_r(base_url)` ?

Comment: Dhara did you get style.css in console?

Comment: crome->F12->network->Css and then refresh your page.

Comment: href=“<?php echo site_url();?>assets/stylesheets/style.css”

Comment: sorry, vasim I am not getting the concept of Consol

Comment: Ok Vasim, Finally i found it. When i go to consol and refresh it, for style.css it shows 404 Not found error in status code @ vasim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `base_url()` should return the base path (without index.php)

You may fix it by adding a backslash like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url();?>/css/style.css">
```

or remove the index.php from your config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'siteurl/ci/';
```

**Another way would be**

define a constant in `constants.php` (in config directory)

```
define("LAYOUT_URL","http://localhost/yoursite/css/");
```

"css" folder here i m assuming is inside application folder. Now you can attach css in page like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo LAYOUT_URL;?>style.css">
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying

Comment: Browser store your css in cache you need clear before page load in some case its reload automatically,In case I can't then we need append version number

Comment: can you look in to browser console

Comment: thanks for fixing your answer. I can understand it now. I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Its cache problem so we need hard rest our browser cache memory

Comment: could be the cache. what makes you sure it is?

Comment: I mean i am also working in wordpress and magento i am face same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting your base url correctly? This is set in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/';
```

Also how are you loading this? You can autoload in `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

or you call it in your method:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

If I were you, I would debug the contents of `base_url` by using `var_dump(base_url)` or `print_r(base_url)` to see what is being produced;

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the error.
The problem was about the base url. In the first i have set the base url as below:

```
$_config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/crudfinal';
```

so. it was actually finding the css file in my computer. So, I have changed it to this:

```
$_config['base_url'] = 'http:// . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . /crudfinal';
```

and finally it worked correctly. But it also works on **$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].**

I have also removed index.php from the url.

Thank you guys for your help :)